# Why Does the Excel.Application App.GetType().Name return ComObject?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

Using VisualStudio 2008, I created a simple Excel 2007 Add-In project.

I add code like the following...

```
var app = Application;
var members = app.GetType().GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public|
               BindingFlags.NonPublic|
               BindingFlags.Instance|
               BindingFlags.Static);
var typeName = app.GetType().Name;
```

... to the ThisAddIn_Startup method (and resolve the missing references to System.Reflection).

When I run the code, the typeName is "_*ComObject".  I was expecting something like "Excel.ApplicationClass".  And, members contains only 26 members, far fewer than the Excel.Application object has.  Stepping through the code, I hover over app and lots of members are shown (all with a blue icon, which is somewhat odd).  However, the type name shown is "System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.*_TransparentProxy", again, not what I expected.

At design time, typing app{dot} to get "Intelli-sense" lists all kinds of members to choose from, i.e., it lists all the Excel.Application members.

Furthermore, if I run the Powershell script...

```
$obj = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$obj | get-member
```

...the output lists all the Excel.Application members.

So, how can I get the MemberInfo objects for all the Excel.Application members in C# at run-time?

Lastly, in case it matters, I choose the Excel 2007 Add-In template when creating the project, then I go to properties->Debug and tell it to start Excel 2010.  This is how I hope to build a 2007 add-in that will also work for Office 2010.  I've done a very similar approach for a Word Add-In with results like I would expect.

Comment: There might be an applicable ("early bound") Interface that is being used.

Comment: You might want to check out this article:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/psingh/CallingCOMComponentFromCSharp12022005231615PM/CallingCOMComponentFromCSharp.aspx

Comment: @Pete the article you recommend helped in getting the members.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question had to do with "Why" I get only 26 members through reflection.  I followed Pete's advice and read the article, and using...

```
var excel = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
var members = excel.GetMembers( ... );
```

... I was able to find over 700 members.

But this still did not answer my question.  I would like to know why I wouldn't get that using normal reflection.  If someone can reply with a good explanation and some references to documentation, I will mark theirs as the answer.